Requirements of Randomness Extractors in KDF?
Are there any randomness extractors that have full detailed proof of their security? How can we measure the entropy compression through the extractor?

Is having a full, detailed proof a requirement for an extractor? As it is the title seems to be rather different than the question in the body. What do you mean with a "full" proof?  Is the proof full even if there is no security proof for the primitives used within the KDF?

@MaartenBodewes I've deleted my answer as upon a rethink, I concur with you that this question is under specified.  I don't like that though as we should help newbies and tease out their inner questions.

Fair enough. I tried to help by indicating that the question is unclear and under-specified and I'm still hoping for an edit of the question. I see three upvotes and no close votes though so apparently people think that it is already clear. To me it isn't (and my close votes are unfortunately absolute as mod).

You'll want to read NIST SP800-90B: https://csrc.nist.gov/pubs/sp/800/90/b/final
Specifically page 15-16 (section 3.1.5.1):
"
Three keyed algorithms have been vetted for a keyed conditioning component:

HMAC, as specified in FIPS 198, with any approved hash function specified in FIPS 180
or FIPS 202,
CMAC, as specified in SP 800-38B, with the AES block cipher (see FIPS 197), and
CBC-MAC, as specified in Appendix F, with the AES block cipher. This Recommendation
does not approve the use of CBC-MAC for purposes other than as a conditioning
component in an RBG.

Three unkeyed functions have been vetted for an unkeyed conditioning component:

Any approved hash function specified in FIPS 180 or FIPS 202,
Hash_df, as specified in SP 800-90A, using any approved hash function specified in FIPS
180 or FIPS 202, and
Block_Cipher_df, as specified in SP800-90A using the AES block cipher (see FIPS 197).
"

Section 3.1.5.1.2 contains a formula you can use to calculate output entropy based on input bitstring length, output bitstring length, and input entropy.
Edit:
To further clarify, the requirement for a cryptographic primitive to be suitable for randomness extraction is that the output must be uniformly distributed and indistinguishable from true randomness as well as having its output appear independent from its input. Generally any secure hash function or block cipher must satisfy these requirements for general usage in cryptography such as encryption and file hashing. The primtives that are listed above are the ones that have been vetted by NIST and as such you can be confident of their security. I am not aware of any primitive that provides a mathematical proof of its security as a randomness extractor specifically.

I think that the question asks for a mathematical proof rather than a standardized MAC function. Of course this would likely work if the "proof" of the PRF considers the hash function or cipher to be secure. But that hasn't been clarified.

Im not aware that theres a mathematical proof for randomness extraction specifically, generally if the underlying hash or block cipher is considered secure for general usage then its secure for randomness extraction as well considering the output must be uniformly random. I took the question as the person looking for a safe primitive that could be used for his KDF but yeah perhaps i should have clarified that.

@MaartenBodewes I've edited my answer to add further clarification.

Randomness extraction has been well studied. It revolves around an acceptable output bias $\epsilon$ away from absolute uniformity.  A good start is the Left Over Hash lemma.
